# Socket Communication Threads stops working randomly for few seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, tcp

**A little Background::**
I have an android application that communicates with another app on local network through a TCP Socket. There are 2 threads in the application, one is for receiving and one is for sending. The app sends and receives a status message every second. And there are other informational messages that are sent and received based on the user's input. The app is more of a kiosk app so it is meant to be running continuously.

**Issue::** Sometimes there are no messages sent or received for around 10-15 seconds. I am logging these messages and I have found that there are no logs for those 10-15 seconds and after that both the thread restarts and connection goes on smoothly again. This is very random.

I have given these threads max priority.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this would be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I am no Android developer, but did you think about how many references you drop while processing network requests? Could that be a garbage collector lag?

Comment: Also maybe it worth to try set TCP_NODELAY on the socket if your messages are short.

Comment: @DmytroY. - I also think that it might be a lag due to gc or due to thread switching perhaps. Is there any way to avoid this, I need this thread to be continuously running.

Comment: AFAIK the best way is to produce less garbage, reuse entities as much as possible so that the references preserved. I am not aware of any java-specific way, though.